# How can i detect if the virtual CD ROM is attached or detached?

Tags: linux, esxi, unix

I have a requirement where i need to check if a virtual CD ROM is attached if yes then read the values and apply it on to the application.

But couldn't find a way to detect if a CD ROM is attached or detached ?

The environment is Cent OS 6 and its a virtual machine deployed (VCenter deployment) using VMWare.

Note: The problem for which i require a solution is how do i detect if the CDROM is attached or detached ?

Comment: `mount | grep <something>`

Answer (score 0):

To see what optical devices are available, you can run this as root:

```
% wodim --devices
```

As for "reading the values and apply it on to the application" you need to be more specific.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?